# why dynamically added fields not removing by clicking remove button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

here is my code,
while adding input field by clicking add button so field will appear but after trying to remove those fields by removing button so it is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //@naresh action dynamic childs
    var next = 0;
    $("#add-more").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var addto = "#field" + next;
        var addRemove = "#field" + (next);
        next = next + 1;
        var newIn = ' <div id="field' + next + '" name="field' + next + '"><!-- Text input--> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-6"> <label for="vat" ></label><input type="text" placeholder="Check In Date" id="datepicker-12"   name="PeriodFrom[]"   class=" datepicker_recurring_start" value=""></div><div class="col-6"><label for="street" ></label><input type="text"  name="PeriodTo[]" placeholder="Check Out Date"  class=" datepicker_recurring_start" value=""></div></div><div class="form-group"><div class="col-6"><label for="vat" ></label><input type="text" id="DoubleBad" name="DoubleBad" placeholder="Double Bed"    value=""></div><div class="col-6"><label for="street" ></label><input type="text" placeholder="Above 12 Years"  id="EXTRA_ADL_ABOVE_12_YRS" name="EXTRA_ADL_ABOVE_12_YRS"   value=""></div></div><div class=" form-group"> <label for="postal-code" > </label><label for="postal-code" ></label><input type="text" id="CNB"  name="MaxCNB[]"   value="" required="required" placeholder="Max Rate CNB"> </div> </div>';
        var newInput = $(newIn);
        var removeBtn = '<button id="remove' + (next - 1) + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >Remove</button></div></div><div id="field">';
        var removeButton = $(removeBtn);
        $(addto).after(newInput);
        $(addRemove).after(removeButton);
        $("#field" + next).attr('data-source', $(addto).attr('data-source'));
        $("#count").val(next);

        $('body').on('click', '.remove-me', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1);
            var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
            $(this).remove();
            $(fieldID).remove();
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="right-panel" class="right-panel">
         <div class="content mt-3" >
            <div class="animated fadeIn">
               <div class="row" style="border:none;">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <div class="card" >
                        <div class="card-header">
                           <div class="row"  >
                              <i class="fa fa-hotel" style="font-size:24px;"></i>
                              <h4 style=" font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;margin-left:20px;"> Manage Hotels </h4>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                           <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admin/Insert-Hotels">
                              <div class="card-body card-block">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-6" id="content">
                                       <label for="vat" ></label><input type="text" id="datepicker_recurring_start"   name="PeriodFrom[]"   class=" datepicker_recurring_start" placeholder="Check In Date" value="" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6" id="content">
                                       <label for="street" ></label><input type="text"  id="datepicker-13" name="PeriodTo[]"  class=" datepicker_recurring_start" placeholder="Check Out Date" value="" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class=" form-group">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                       <label for="vat" ></label><input type="text" id="DoubleBed" name="MaxDoubleBed[]"    value="" placeholder="Max Rate Double Bed" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                       <label for="postal-code" ></label><input type="text" id="SigleBed" name="MaxSigleBad[]"   value="" placeholder="Max Rate Sigle Bed" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class=" form-group">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                       <label for="postal-code" ></label><input type="text" id="CNB"  name="MaxCNB[]"   value="" required="required" placeholder="Max Rate CNB">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                       <label for="postal-code" ></label> 
                                       <select name="cityID" id="cityID" class="-md " required="required">
                                          <option value="">Select Country and City</option>
                                          <?php
                                             foreach ($fatch_hotels_country as $key => $fatch_hotels_country) {
                                             
                                                 echo "<option value='".$fatch_hotels_country->id."'>".$fatch_hotels_country->citiesName."</option>";
                                             }
                                             ?>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class=" form-group">
                                    <label for="postal-code" ></label>
                                    <label for="company" ></label><input type="text" id="HotelName" name="Star"   value="" required="required" placeholder="Star">
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <!-----------------------------------   Add More Data Start -------------------------->
                              <div class=" form-group">
                                 <div id="field">
                                    <div id="field0">
                                    </div>
                                 </div >
                                 <!-----------------------------------   Add More Data End -------------------------->
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="reset"  class="btn btn-danger" value="Reset">
                        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Insert">
                        <button id="add-more" name="add-more" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

here you can see,
I'm trying to add input fields by clicking "add more"  button right below right side.
while fields are displaying you can see "remove" button right top of dynamically added input fields.
while clicking on that button so those fields are not remove.

Comment: because you add a div with the id of next but your remove id is next - 1?  Also move your delegated bind out of the add bind, the point of event delegation is that it will automatically be bound to dynamically added elements so you do not need to bind it inside another event

Comment: Check the DOM you are creating here using your browser dev tools. You have `#field0` right there from the beginning. Clicking your add button adds a remove button with id `#remove0`, and a new group of fields in `#field1` after it. `#field0` stays empty, and this is what your button removes. (Also, you are creating `#field` multiple times.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the div id to be removed is getting wrong so

Change

```
var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1);
var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
```

to

```
 var fieldNum = +this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1);
 var fieldID = "#field" + parseFloat(fieldNum + 1);
```

and Add

```
next = fieldNum;
```

in `$('body').on('click', '.remove-me', function(e) {`

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/95wyrfdL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //@naresh action dynamic childs
  var next = 0;
  $("#add-more").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var addto = "#field" + next;
      var addRemove = "#field" + (next);
      next = next + 1;
      var newIn = ' <div id="field' + next + '" name="field' + next + '"><!-- Text input--> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-6"> <label for="vat" ></label><input type="text" placeholder="Check In Date" id="datepicker-12"   name="PeriodFrom[]"   class=" datepicker_recurring_start" value=""></div><div class="col-6"><label for="street" ></label><input type="text"  name="PeriodTo[]" placeholder="Check Out Date"  class=" datepicker_recurring_start" value=""></div></div><div class="form-group"><div class="col-6"><label for="vat" ></label><input type="text" id="DoubleBad" name="DoubleBad" placeholder="Double Bed"    value=""></div><div class="col-6"><label for="street" ></label><input type="text" placeholder="Above 12 Years"  id="EXTRA_ADL_ABOVE_12_YRS" name="EXTRA_ADL_ABOVE_12_YRS"   value=""></div></div><div class=" form-group"> <label for="postal-code" > </label><label for="postal-code" ></label><input type="text" id="CNB"  name="MaxCNB[]"   value="" required="required" placeholder="Max Rate CNB"> </div> </div>';
      var newInput = $(newIn);
      var removeBtn = '<button id="remove' + (next - 1) + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >Remove</button></div></div><div id="field">';
      var removeButton = $(removeBtn);
      $(addto).after(newInput);
      $(addRemove).after(removeButton);
      $("#field" + next).attr('data-source', $(addto).attr('data-source'));
     $("#count").val(next);
 });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove-me', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1);
      var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
      $(this).remove();
      $(fieldID).remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: they are removing on 2nd attempt not first attempt. means while adding first time so it is not removing by remove button but if you are added two time and only last one removing by remove button not first time added input fields

Comment: You have to call your ".remove-me" click event outside of "add-more" click event . Why you are not using to remove $(this).closest('div').remove();

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html><head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script><style type="text/css">.as-console-wrapper { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; border-top: 1px solid #000; display: none; }
.as-console { background: #e9e9e9; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
.as-console-row { display: table-row; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; }
.as-console-row:after { display: table-cell; padding: 3px 6px; color: rgba(0,0,0,.35); border: 1px solid #ccc; content: attr(data-date); vertical-align: top; }
.as-console-row + .as-console-row > * { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; padding: 3px 5px; display: table-cell; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle; }
.as-console-error:before { content: 'Error: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-assert:before { content: 'Assertion failed: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-info:before { content: 'Info: '; color: #00f; }
.as-console-warning:before { content: 'Warning: '; color: #e90 }
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-moz-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-ms-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
.as-console-row-code, .as-console-row:after { -webkit-animation: flash 1s; -moz-animation: flash 1s; -ms-animation: flash 1s; animation: flash 1s; }</style>
    </head>
<body>
    

   
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
   
      <div id="right-panel" class="right-panel">
         <div class="content mt-3">
            <div class="animated fadeIn">
               <div class="row" style="border:none;">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                           <div class="row">
                              <i class="fa fa-hotel" style="font-size:24px;"></i>
                              <h4 style=" font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;margin-left:20px;"> Manage Hotels </h4>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                           <form method="post" action="&lt;?php echo base_url(); ?&gt;Admin/Insert-Hotels">
                              <div class="card-body card-block">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-6" id="content">
                                       <label for="vat"></label><input type="text" id="datepicker_recurring_start" name="PeriodFrom[]" class=" datepicker_recurring_start" placeholder="Check In Date" value="" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6" id="content">
                                       <label for="street"></label><input type="text" id="datepicker-13" name="PeriodTo[]" class=" datepicker_recurring_start" placeholder="Check Out Date" value="" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class=" form-group">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                       <label for="vat"></label><input type="text" id="DoubleBed" name="MaxDoubleBed[]" value="" placeholder="Max Rate Double Bed" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                       <label for="postal-code"></label><input type="text" id="SigleBed" name="MaxSigleBad[]" value="" placeholder="Max Rate Sigle Bed" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class=" form-group">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                       <label for="postal-code"></label><input type="text" id="CNB" name="MaxCNB[]" value="" required="required" placeholder="Max Rate CNB">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                       <label for="postal-code"></label> 
                                       <select name="cityID" id="cityID" class="-md " required="required">
                                          <option value="">Select Country and City</option>
                                          <!--?php
                                             foreach ($fatch_hotels_country as $key =--> $fatch_hotels_country) {
                                             
                                                 echo "<option value="&quot;.$fatch_hotels_country->id.&quot;">".$fatch_hotels_country-&gt;citiesName."</option>";
                                             }
                                             ?&gt;
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class=" form-group">
                                    <label for="postal-code"></label>
                                    <label for="company"></label><input type="text" id="HotelName" name="Star" value="" required="required" placeholder="Star">
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <!-----------------------------------   Add More Data Start -------------------------->
                              <div class=" form-group">
                                 <div id="field">
                                    <div id="field0">
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <!-----------------------------------   Add More Data End -------------------------->
                              </div>
                        </form></div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Reset">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Insert">
                        <button id="add-more" name="add-more" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
      
   

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    //@naresh action dynamic childs
    var next = 0;
    $("#add-more").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var addto = "#field" + next;
        var addRemove = "#field" + (next);
        next = next + 1;
        var newIn = ' <div id="field' + next + '" name="field' + next + '"><!-- Text input--> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-6"> <label for="vat" ></label><input type="text" placeholder="Check In Date" id="datepicker-12"   name="PeriodFrom[]"   class=" datepicker_recurring_start" value=""></div><div class="col-6"><label for="street" ></label><input type="text"  name="PeriodTo[]" placeholder="Check Out Date"  class=" datepicker_recurring_start" value=""></div></div><div class="form-group"><div class="col-6"><label for="vat" ></label><input type="text" id="DoubleBad" name="DoubleBad" placeholder="Double Bed"    value=""></div><div class="col-6"><label for="street" ></label><input type="text" placeholder="Above 12 Years"  id="EXTRA_ADL_ABOVE_12_YRS" name="EXTRA_ADL_ABOVE_12_YRS"   value=""></div></div><div class=" form-group"> <label for="postal-code" > </label><label for="postal-code" ></label><input type="text" id="CNB"  name="MaxCNB[]"   value="" required="required" placeholder="Max Rate CNB"> </div> </div>';
        var newInput = $(newIn);
        var removeBtn = '<button id="remove' + (next - 1) + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >Remove</button></div></div><div class="field"></div>';
        var removeButton = $(removeBtn);
        $(addto).after(newInput);
        $(addRemove).after(removeButton);
        $("#field" + next).attr('data-source', $(addto).attr('data-source'));
        $("#count").val(next);

        $('body').on('click', '.remove-me', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fieldNum = parseInt(this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1))+1;
            var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
            $(this).remove();
            $(fieldID).remove();
        });
    });

});
    </script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Mine pleasure Buddy :)